# Laravel: POST method returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, post, laravel-5, routes

I have a `POST` route in my `api.php` file, and it is like this:

```
Route::group(
    ['namespace' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::post('parent/signup', 'ParentController@signUp');
}
);
```

And I am trying to access this url in `postman` as this is an `api` route. But when I send request to this `route`, this `exception` occurs:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

I am definitely sending a post request as shown in the shot below:

[image]

I ran `php artisan route:list` and this route is a POST one.

```
| POST | api\/parent\/signup | | App\\Http\\Controllers\\api\\ParentController@signUp
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help?

Comment: Why do you add `public` in your url? Standard Laravel applications are served from public, but you don't need to add it to the url. Could you try `example.com/api/parent/signup`?

Comment: Without public it returns 404 error.

Comment: its `signUp`. As shown.

Comment: what headers you send with postman?

Comment: this is the header: `Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: Check if with postman you send some parameter that changes the request (for example the "method" parameter).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a same problem on a half of month ago.

The reason is when I post on valid route, it **redirects** from http to https (configured by .htaccess), so "POST" method becomes "GET" and you see a MethodNotAllowedException.

Check your browser and follow the request, you may see the accurate problem.

Comment: O man, you saved my day. That was exactly the issue. I changed it to `https://` and it worked. Thanks a lot. Cheers!

Comment: I also have the same issue! And I'm also connecting to `https://` when I'm hitting the API! But the POST method still doesn't work: `https://example.com/app/public/api/test`. Can you explain more on this?

Comment: @Saani what was the solution? Do i have to update my .htaccess file? what do i have to update with? I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score -1):

The problem should be the route namespace, you are not using it properly.

Try to use the route group:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::post('parent/signup', 'ParentController@signup');
});
```

Comment: this error pops by changing it to prefix: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: Wrong. The api.php file already prefixes `api` to all routes in the route service provider.

Comment: Forgot he was talking about "api.php", thanks for your precisation.