# Laravel and passport: POST method returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, laravel-passport

I've been looking all over the internet for 2 days for a solution for my problem to no avail. I'm new to Laravel and API's as a whole, so bear with me.

I've managed to create a working REST API with the use of `passport` via `composer`:

The routes in `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::post('login', 'PassportController@login');
Route::post('register', 'PassportController@register');
```

And the controller code for `login` and `register`:

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], 200);
    }
    else{
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
    $success['name'] =  $user->name;
    return response()->json(['success'=>$success], 200);
}
```

This API works on `localhost` but not when i open to the internet with:

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.x.x --port 80
```

connected to a bought domain via port forwarding.

only the `GET` methods works, but the `POST` methods gives the error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed

As far as i could figure out, it has something to do with redirecting from http to https:

> I have a same problem on a half of month ago. 
>   The reason is when I post on valid route, it redirects from http to
>   https (configured by .htaccess), so "POST" method becomes "GET" and
>   you see a MethodNotAllowedException.
>   Check your browser and follow the request, you may see the accurate
>   problem.

from [Laravel: POST method returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404530/laravel-post-method-returns-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

If this is the case for me as well, how do I fix the problem? The `.htaccess` file has nothing with `https` in it. Sorry if the answer is in the quoted answer but it don't know how to use that information.

**UPDATE:**
I found something about a csrf token problem https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/405-method-not-allowed-laravel-55-api-passport-help. But apperently it could be fixed via entering the URIs for the `POST` methods in the `VerifyCsrfToken` file in the `Middleware` folder, like so:

```
protected $except = [
   'api/register',
   'api/login'
];
```

I still get the MethodNotAllowed error..... This is starting to really annoy as there seem to be no answers online. HELP!

Comment: Try adding a forward slash in front of your route. `Route::post('/login', 'PassportController@login');`

Comment: @Chirs Laravel automatically adds the `/` if it's not there.

Comment: Is there no other answer? do i really have to find something else than passport to authenticate my API? that can't be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apperently i was missing the "www" when i was doing requests.

I had the following in postman:

```
mysite.com/api/login
```

but i needed:

```
www.mysite.com/api/login
```

Embarrassingly small rookie mistake that costed me 5 days to figure out... I hope this will help any new webdevelopers that run into the same issue so they don't waste time like i did.