# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, post

I have a very weird problem. I have a post route but I receive an error that **The GET method is not supported for this route.**

This is my web.php function:

```
Route::post('/sender',function () {
    $text = request()->text;
    event(new FormSubmitted($text));
});
```

I'm definitely sending a post request.
I've already checked this: [Laravel: POST method returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404530/laravel-post-method-returns-methodnotallowedhttpexception)

But the chosen answer is unclear.

My View Code:

```
<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>

{{ csrf_field() }}



<form action="/sender" method="post>
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<input type="text" name="content"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: How are you serving your application? What web server software are you using?

Comment: please provide your view code, it looks like you might be trying use a GET method on a POST route

Comment: Please check your `POST` requests are not being redirected to `GET` requests by your server. I recently discovered this with apache which redirected based on a trailing `/` in the request url.

Comment: @CodeBoyCode Added

Comment: @thisiskelvin How can I check that?

Comment: @Joe See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored)

Comment: <form action="/sender" method="post> missing quotation mark after post

Comment: I tried changing the post that I have to GET request and this isn't throwing any errors. Is that normal?

Comment: Fixed the typo and nothing changed

Comment: Am getting the same using postman POST

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this might just be a typo error - you have missed a quotation mark (") after 'post'

**view:**

```
<form action="/sender" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="text" name="content"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**controller**

```
Route::post('/sender',function () {
    $name = request->fname;
    $content = request->content
    event(new FormSubmitted($name, $content));
});
```

EDIT: updated controller code, you were requesting the data from an input called 'text', but there wasn't any inputs with the name of 'text' in the view, only input type's

Comment: Fixed it but nothing changed. I tried changing the post that I have to "GET" request and this isn't throwing any errors. Is that normal?

Comment: what do you mean Joe - personally the best way of doing this for me would be to open the form with action and method, and then declare your CSRF token, and then your inputs, remembering to close your form with </form> (i know you haven't included </form> within your code, have you done that within your code?

Comment: hey Joe I just noticed something wrong with your controller aswell

Comment: Did this fix your issue @Joe

Answer (score 0):

First, check you define route proper or not by `php artisan route:list` command

Blade file

```
<form action="{{ route('sender') }}" method="post">
@csrf
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

<input type="text" name="content"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Route

```
Route::post('/sender',function () {
    $text = request()->fname; //access by input field name
    event(new FormSubmitted($text));
})->name('sender');

or

Route::post('/sender', 'UserController@sender')->name('sender');
```

if you're using route with controller then your controller seems like that

```
public function sender(Request $request)
{
    $fname = $request->fname;
    event(new FormSubmitted($fname));
}
```